# print 4x6 image using UIPrintInteractionController

Tags: ios, swift, uiprintinteractioncntrler, uiprintinfo

I am trying to print a 4x6 image through the printController, however, when it prints it cuts off some of the image. The code I am using is below.

```
@IBAction func doPrint(_ sender: Any) {
    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
    printInfo.outputType = .photo
    printInfo.jobName = "PrintPhoto"
    printInfo.orientation = .landscape

    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
    printController.printInfo = printInfo
    printController.printingItem = newImage
    printController.showsNumberOfCopies = false
    printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

These are border-less 4x6 prints and it is cutting off approx 0.25 inch, resizing the image produces same result.

Comment: you can configure the size with papersize of uiprintpaper https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprintpaper/1623529-papersize

Comment: I am aware you can set papersize, however, that is not the issue. Its selecting 4x6 papersize but the image is being clipped.